# Google map in JSF is not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I have to show markers in google map using JSF and javascript.but i don't know the problem.  Same code is working well in jsp but not working well in jsf even map not showing map on page. Code for JSF page is given as follows:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <head> 
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
        <title>Google Maps Multiple Markers</title> 
        <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head> 
    <body>
        <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
           // <![CDATA[
            alert("hello");
            var locations = [
                   <ui:repeat value = "#{loadBean.googleMapLocations}" var = "googleLocation"  varStatus = "status" >
                    ['#{googleLocation.location}', '#{googleLocation.latitude}', '#{googleLocation.longitude}']
                    < c:if test = "${!status.last}" >
                    ,
                    < /c:if>
                    < /ui:repeat>
            ]
                    alert(locations);
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 10,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng("${loadBean.centerLatitude}", "${loadBean.centerLongitude}"),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            });

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

            var marker, i;

            for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                    map: map
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                    return function() {
                        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    }
                })(marker, i));
            }
           function saveForm(){
                alert("helo world");
            }
             ]]>
        </script>
        <table>
            <c:forEach var="googleLocation" items="${loadBean.googleMapLocations}">
                <tr><td>${googleLocation.latitude}</td><td>${googleLocation.longitude}</td></tr>  
            </c:forEach>
            CENTER<tr><td>${loadBean.centerLatitude}</td><td>${loadBean.centerLongitude}</td></tr>
        </table>
        <f:view>
        <h:form>
        <p:commandButton type="button" onclick="return saveForm();" value="Button" /></h:form></f:view>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using ui repeat instead of forEach.